# Is this definition of mole correct?

Tags: stoichiometry, terminology, mole

Chemical engineers define one mole as the amount of a substance which possess as many entities as $12\ \mathrm g$ of $\ce{^{12}C}$.

The number of atoms in $12\ \mathrm g$ of $\ce{^{12}C}$ is $6.022 \times 10^{23}$ which is a constant by its definition.

Now come to the relevant definition which is given in my textbook that defines one mole of a substance as the atomic mass, molecular mass or formula mass in grams.

Is this definition correct?

Comment: It is the right definition for now. I remember reading about a sphere of silicon which was being proposed for a new standard. The twist here that that the definition of a kilogram is being considered for replacement too.

Comment: @MaxW can you explain me this chemical equation? $Zn + 2HCl = ZnCl_2 + H_2$? I think, I can better explain my problem then.

Comment: I don't understand what there is to explain about the reaction.

Comment: Ok listen.. The equation is balanced. What is the $"2"$ there before $HCl$? If it tells that on the right hand side there are two atoms of Hydrogen and two of Chlorine as well . And two are there on left hand side of Hydrogen and chlorine. Then equation is said to balanced. What my textbook writes just after it is that the $"2"$ before $HCl$ tells us that there are two moles of $HCl$ included in the reaction.  So my problem solicits that if $2$ is there to show no. of molecules then how it is defining the no. of moles at same time?

Comment: @SufyanNaeem Wow, I just flagged your comment above 'not constructive' because it has nothing to do with the question but now I realise how it might actually … You are *badly* misunderstanding things, and your question is a victim of the [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: Chiefly the problem is with the definition given in textbook. Above problem is a result of that problem.

Comment: Please clarify what your actual *problem* is.

Comment: My actual problem is as stated in question. That problem is rising more problems when dealing with stoichiometry. Read my comment first and then question. I am sure, you will get my problem then.

Comment: A balanced chemical; equation shows the stoichiometry as you pointed out. The stoichiometry is a just the "count". A mole is just a large counting number - sort of like a million, a billion, or a trillion. It is useful as a counting number in chemistry because it gets a large enough number of atoms or molecules so that that many atoms has a "useful" weight. You can weigh 12 grams of carbon on a "regular balance" but you can't weigh one atom of carbon. You can't just tie the mole to the molecular weight of carbon since carbon has multiple isotopes.

Comment: Alright @volunteers  Please tell me about this. "A balanced equation MUST have EQUAL numbers of EACH type of atom on BOTH sides of the arrow." Now My book at a place says that the $2$ prefixed with $HCl$ is telling us that there are two atoms of hydrogen and Chlorine each included in reaction. Next to it, it says that that $2$ is defining no. of moles (of $HCl$) included in reaction. But according to first definition given, $2$ moles of $HCl$ contains $2 \times 6.022 \times 10^{23}$. This really mixes up.

Comment: @SufyanNaeem You should read that $2$ as meaning $2x$ and read any (unwritten) $1$’s as $x$. The $2$ just says ‘double the number of where there is no $2$’. In no way at all is the meaning of that $2$ tied to the definition of a mole. And in no way at all does it say ‘exactly two of type $x$’. Otherwise the reaction would stop after two molecules of $\ce{HCl}$ have reacted.

Comment: @MaxW, I am close. Just give me your decision whether the definition given in my textbook of mole is correct or not?

Comment: The first line of your question is the correct definition of a mole.

Comment: And other one???

Comment: Is practically always equivalent within experimental error.

Comment: ‘Yes (unless you ask a theoretical physicist)’

Comment: @Jan you say that $2$ is a sort of or a coefficient (simply a number) which doesn't tell us the no. of moles but atoms however. $2H_2O$ doesn't mean $2$ moles of water but it calculate us the total number of atoms however included in reaction. There are 4 hydrogen atoms and 2 oxygen.

Comment: Sufyan I don't know exactly how your book's statements are worded to explain the confusion which we are dancing about. In chemistry we slip between talking about individual molecules in a chemical reaction and the number of moles involved rather frequently. So one mole of zinc reacts with two moles of HCl in the reaction, or one molecule of Zn reactions with two molecules of HCl. The real point here is that mass (or weight) isn't such a count. So 1 kilogram of Zinc and two kilograms of HCl are not the correct proportions for the reaction. That is why chemists need "moles."

Comment: $2$ ***is*** a coefficient. And it *only* tells us the ***ratios*** of different entities.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The mole is a base unit as specified in the *Système international d’unités* (SI) by the *bureau international des poids et mesures.* Its decisive definition is that published in [French](http://www.bipm.org/fr/CGPM/db/14/3/):

> 1. La mole est la quantité de matière d’un système contenant autant d’entités élémentaires qu’il y a d’atomes dans 0,012 kilogramme de carbone 12 ; son symbole est « *mol* ».
> 2. Lorsqu’on emploie la mole, les entités élémentaires doivent être spécifiées et peuvent être des atomes, des molécules, des ions, des électrons, d’autres particules ou des groupements spécifiés de telles particules.
> 3. La mole est une unité de base du Système international d’unités.

The proposal was brought forth by the International Union of Pure and Applied Physics (IUPAP), the International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry (IUPAC) and the International Organisation for Standardization (ISO). As with all SI texts, the decisive French version has a semi-official [English translation](http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si_brochure_8_en.pdf):

> 1. The mole is the amount of substance of a system which contains as many
>      elementary entities as there are atoms in $0.012$ kilogram of carbon 12; its
>      symbol is “mol”.
> 2. When the mole is used, the elementary entities must be specified and may be
>      atoms, molecules, ions, electrons, other particles, or specified groups of
>      such particles.

(The third point is not translated.)

This definition is more or less identical with the one in your first paragraph.

In practice and well within experimental error, this means that your later definition will hold true for any substance. I.e. take $1~\mathrm{mol}$ of an entity and the combined mass of that mole will be the same numerical value in grams as a single entity has in atomic mass units ($\mathrm{u}$). It is not the correct definition, and for any entity that is not carbon-12 the masses will differ slightly (but well within margin of your macroscopic experimental error) but it is good enough for most contexts.

---

A redefinition of the SI units is being discussed and will likely be adopted at the 26<sup>th</sup> General Conference of Weights and Measures in autumn 2018. This would redefine the mole in a way that the Avogadro constant is defined to be numerically exactly $6.02214 \cdot 10^{23}~\mathrm{mol^{-1}}$ (with a few further digits appended to the end of the number that yet need agreement). This would mean that the new definition of the mole would be along the lines of:

> The mole, mol, is the unit of amount of substance of a specified elementary entity, which may be an atom, molecule, ion, electron, any other particle or a specified group of such particles; its magnitude is set by fixing the numerical value of the Avogadro constant to be equal to exactly $6.02214X \cdot 10^{23}$ when it is expressed in the unit $\mathrm{mol^{-1}}$.

Currently, the Avogadro constant must be measured experimentally giving a value of $6.022140857(74)~\mathrm{mol^{-1}}$; the digits in brackets express the numerical uncertainty.

This *will* mean that $1~\mathrm{mol}$ of carbon-12 atoms will no longer have the mass of exactly $12~\mathrm{g}$ (but again, it will be well within experimental error for everybody not practising theoretical physics).

---

To answer the follow-up question you asked in the comments: The coefficients in chemical equations such as

$$\ce{Zn + 2 HCl -> ZnCl2 + H2}$$

are always and exclusively to be understood as *ratio coefficients.* Thus, instead of thinking *one atom* or *one mole of zinc*, think *amount $n$ of zinc* and *amount $2n$ of $\ce{HCl}$.*